# Modbus Packet Reading

Tags: uart, modbus, pymodbus

It is known that the data I need to read is 9926 bytes of data, and my hardware and software communication protocols are serial and Modbus ASCII. Modbus ASCII protocol does not seem to be able to read such a large amount of data at one time, can I take a packet reading approach, or do you have any better suggestions?

I'm trying to read data from my Thermopile Infrared Array, its size is 80*62*2+6. the software protocol is Modbus ASCII, the hardware protocol is UART.

here is my code:

```py
import serial
import time

try:
    # 打开串口
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate=115200,
        stopbits=1,
        parity='N',
        bytesize=8,
        timeout=1
    )

while True:
    # 发送Modbus ASCII请求
    request_message = "51 75 65 72 79 54 0D 0A"
    request_bytes = bytes.fromhex(request_message.replace(" ", ""))
    print("Sent data:", request_bytes)
    ser.write(request_bytes)

    # 等待响应
    time.sleep(20)

    expected_length = 80 * 62 * 2 + 6
    response_bytes = b''

    while len(response_bytes) < expected_length:
        remaining_bytes = expected_length - len(response_bytes)
        print("Before reading response")
        try:
            chunk = ser.read(remaining_bytes)
            len_response_bytes = len(response_bytes)
            print("读到的数据:", chunk)
            print("读到的数据的长度:", len_response_bytes)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading response:{e}")
        print("After reading response")
        response_bytes += chunk

    # 处理响应数据
    # 显示响应数据的十六进制表示
    print("Received data (hex):", response_bytes)
    response_hex = ' '.join(format(byte, '02X') for byte in response_bytes)
    print("Received data (hex):", response_hex)
    # 间隔5秒再次读取
    time.sleep(5)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
finally:
    # 关闭串口
    ser.close()
```

Comment: When making a Modbus request you specify which register (or coil) to start with and how many you want. There is a limit to the amount of data that can be returned (with Modbus ASCII I believe that is 252 bytes). However you can make multiple requests (e.g. register 1-100, 101-200 etc). Would need more info to provide a proper answer (e.g. a link to the manual that details the devices Modbus implementation).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I get you for making multiple requests, but my protocol said that "Read all the temperature" using the telegram which is  "51 75 65 72 79 54 0D 0A ", not by giving "Start address and data length", so I'm comfused how to read my response by packets. I included my code at the end of the question, please check.

Comment: That does not look like Modbus to me (I'm not aware of function code 0x75). You would need to provide significantly more info (and confirm its not a hardware issue).

Comment: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/5712. PLS PROVIDE DEVICE MANUAL (LINK TO).